# Rtf Property of RichTextBox continuously changes

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

When embedding a file inside a `RichTextBox` (for example by pasting it), the `Rtf` property continuously changes afterwards. When debugging, you can see at every step that the property has changed.

The changes only occur at some lines and seem to be random (sometimes a value of the `Rtf` property occurs again after 100 changes, sometimes after 800, or anywhere between).

As no events are raised and the behaviour and UI is not affected, this is normally not a problem. But I want to get changed sections and therefore need a steady value in `Rtf` as long as there are no actual changes made.

How can I solve this problem?

---

Some code to reproduce:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class RTFForm : Form
{
    public RTFForm()
    {
        RichTextBox rtb  = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        rtb.EnableAutoDragDrop = true;
        this.Controls.Add(rtb);

        rtb.Rtf = GetRTFContentFile();

        List<string> rtfList = new List<string>();
        int changes = 0;
        while(!rtfList.Contains(rtb.Rtf))
        {
            rtfList.Add( rtb.Rtf);
            changes++;
        }
        Debug.Print("changes until repeat: " + changes);    //set a breakpoint here. It is eventually reached

        string rtf = "";
        changes = 0;
        while (rtf != rtb.Rtf)
        {
            rtf = rtb.Rtf;
            changes++;
        }
        Debug.Print("changes until staying equal:" + changes);  //set a breakpoint here. It is never reached
    }

    private string GetRTFContentFile()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1031{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}");
        sb.Append("\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\f0\\fs20{\\object\\objemb{\\*\\objclass Package}\\objw615\\objh810{\\*\\objdata ");
        sb.Append("01050000");
        sb.Append("02000000");
        sb.Append("08000000");
        sb.Append("5061636b61676500");
        sb.Append("00000000");
        sb.Append("00000000");
        sb.Append("27010000");
        sb.Append("020066696c652e74787400433a5c55736572735c6dfc6c6c65725c4465736b746f705c66696c65");
        sb.Append("2e74787400000003002d000000433a5c55736572735c4d4c4c45527e315c417070446174615c4c");
        sb.Append("6f63616c5c54656d705c66696c652e747874000e0000007468697320697320612066696c652c00");
        sb.Append("000043003a005c00550073006500720073005c004d004c004c00450052007e0031005c00410070");
        sb.Append("00700044006100740061005c004c006f00630061006c005c00540065006d0070005c0066006900");
        sb.Append("6c0065002e0074007800740008000000660069006c0065002e007400780074002000000043003a");
        sb.Append("005c00550073006500720073005c006d00fc006c006c00650072005c004400650073006b007400");
        sb.Append("6f0070005c00660069006c0065002e00740078007400");
        sb.Append("01050000");
        sb.Append("05000000");
        sb.Append("0d000000");
        sb.Append("4d45544146494c455049435400");
        sb.Append("a6050000");
        sb.Append("8ff8ffff");
        sb.Append("7c0e0000");
        sb.Append("0800a60571070000");
        sb.Append("0100090000033a0700000200210600000000050000000b0200000000050000000c02350028001c");
        sb.Append("000000fb02f4ff000000000000900100000001000000005365676f65205549002c0a4588d0f80a");
        sb.Append("84adef067093787680017c76c92c6687040000002d010000050000000902000000000500000001");
        sb.Append("02ffffff00a5000000410bc6008800200020000000000020002000000004002800000020000000");
        sb.Append("400000000100010000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffff");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000f800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff80000");
        sb.Append("0ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800");
        sb.Append("000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800001ff800003ff888807ff8");
        sb.Append("0000fff80001ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff21060000410b46006600200020000000");
        sb.Append("000020002000000004002800000020000000200000000100180000000000000c00000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f9fafaf9fafaf9fafaf9f9f9f9");
        sb.Append("f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f8f8f8f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f7f7f6f7f7f6f7f7f6f7f7f6");
        sb.Append("f7f7f6f7f7fbfbfb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fdfdfdfafafafafafaf9fafaf9fafaf9");
        sb.Append("fafaf9f9f9f9f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f7f7f7f7f7f6f7f7f6");
        sb.Append("f7f7fbfbfb000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6");
        sb.Append("d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fdfdfdfafbfbfafafafafafafafafaf9fafaf9");
        sb.Append("fafaf9fafaf9f9f9f9f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f7f7fb");
        sb.Append("fbfb000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0");
        sb.Append("ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fdfdfdfbfbfbfafbfbfafbfbfafbfbfafafafafafafa");
        sb.Append("fafaf9fafaf9fafaf9fafaf9f9f9f9f9f9f8f9f9f8f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8fbfcfc00");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000d6d6d6fdfefefbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfafbfbfafbfbfafafafa");
        sb.Append("fafafafafaf9fafaf9fafaf9fafaf8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f8f8f8f8f8f7f8f8fbfcfc00000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000d6d6d6fefefefcfcfcfbfcfcfbfcfcfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfafbfbfafbfbfa");
        sb.Append("fbfbfafafafafafafafafaf9f9f9f9f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9fcfcfc00000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000d6d6d6fefefefcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfcfcfbfcfcfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfa");
        sb.Append("fbfbfafbfbfafafaf9fafaf9fafaf9f9f9f9f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9fcfcfc00000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000d6d6d6fefefefcfdfdfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfcfcfbfcfcfbfbfbfbfbfbfb");
        sb.Append("fbfbfafbfbfafafafafafaf9fafaf9fafaf9fafaf9f9f9fcfcfc00000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8f0ebe4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6");
        sb.Append("d6d6fefefefdfdfdfdfdfdfcfdfdfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfcfcfbfcfcfbfbfbfb");
        sb.Append("fbfbfafbfbfafafafafafafafafaf9fafaf9fafafcfdfd00000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8ea");
        sb.Append("eaea000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fe");
        sb.Append("fefefdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfcfdfdfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfcfcfb");
        sb.Append("fbfbfafbfbfafbfbd6d6d6cececebfbfbfb8b8b800000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfc");
        sb.Append("fdfdfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfbfbb2b2b2abababa9a9a9a9a9a9afafafb7b7b700");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fefefefd");
        sb.Append("fdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfcfdfdfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfbfbc6");
        sb.Append("c6c6f5f5f5f4f4f4e3e3e3bbbbbb62626200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000d6d6d6fefefefefefefdfefefdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfcfdfdfcfcfcfc");
        sb.Append("fcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfcfcfbfcfccececefafafaebebebc9c9c96c6c6c00000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fffefeece9e9c4");
        sb.Append("bfbff2eff0fdfdfdece9e9c4bfbff2eff0fcfcfcece9e9c4bfbff2eff0fcfcfcfcfcfccdcdcde4");
        sb.Append("e4e4c8c8c866666600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000d6d6d6fffefebdb8b8000000dddadafdfdfdbdb8b8000000dddadafcfdfdbd");
        sb.Append("b8b8000000dddadafcfcfceaeaeac3c3c3c7c7c763636300000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fffefeece9e9c4bfbff3");
        sb.Append("f0f0fdfdfdece9e9c4bfbff3f0f0fdfdfdece9e9c4bfbff3f0f0fcfcfcdcdcdcbfbfbfaeacac00");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000d6d6d6d6d6d6d6d6d6f6f3f3d6d6d6d6d6d6d6d6d6f6f3f3d6d6d6d6d6d6d6d6d6f6");
        sb.Append("f3f3d6d6d6d6d6d6ccccccc3c1c1c7c7c700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000005000000020101000000050000002e01060000000a0000002105080066696c652e74787421");
        sb.Append("0014001c000000fb021000070000000000bc02000000000102022253797374656d0000c92c6687");
        sb.Append("00000a0022008a0100000000ffffffff0caeef06040000002d010100030000000000");
        sb.Append("}{\\result{\\pict\\wmetafile8\\picw1446\\pich1905\\picwgoal615\\pichgoal810 ");
        sb.Append("0100090000033a0700000200210600000000050000000b0200000000050000000c02350028001c");
        sb.Append("000000fb02f4ff000000000000900100000001000000005365676f65205549002c0a4588d0f80a");
        sb.Append("84adef067093787680017c76c92c6687040000002d010000050000000902000000000500000001");
        sb.Append("02ffffff00a5000000410bc6008800200020000000000020002000000004002800000020000000");
        sb.Append("400000000100010000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffff");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000f800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff80000");
        sb.Append("0ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800");
        sb.Append("000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800000ff800001ff800003ff888807ff8");
        sb.Append("0000fff80001ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff21060000410b46006600200020000000");
        sb.Append("000020002000000004002800000020000000200000000100180000000000000c00000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f9fafaf9fafaf9fafaf9f9f9f9");
        sb.Append("f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f8f8f8f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f7f7f6f7f7f6f7f7f6f7f7f6");
        sb.Append("f7f7f6f7f7fbfbfb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fdfdfdfafafafafafaf9fafaf9fafaf9");
        sb.Append("fafaf9f9f9f9f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f7f7f7f7f7f6f7f7f6");
        sb.Append("f7f7fbfbfb000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6");
        sb.Append("d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fdfdfdfafbfbfafafafafafafafafaf9fafaf9");
        sb.Append("fafaf9fafaf9f9f9f9f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f7f7fb");
        sb.Append("fbfb000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0");
        sb.Append("ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fdfdfdfbfbfbfafbfbfafbfbfafbfbfafafafafafafa");
        sb.Append("fafaf9fafaf9fafaf9fafaf9f9f9f9f9f9f8f9f9f8f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8f7f8f8fbfcfc00");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000d6d6d6fdfefefbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfafbfbfafbfbfafafafa");
        sb.Append("fafafafafaf9fafaf9fafaf9fafaf8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f8f8f8f8f8f7f8f8fbfcfc00000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000d6d6d6fefefefcfcfcfbfcfcfbfcfcfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfafbfbfafbfbfa");
        sb.Append("fbfbfafafafafafafafafaf9f9f9f9f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9fcfcfc00000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000d6d6d6fefefefcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfcfcfbfcfcfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfa");
        sb.Append("fbfbfafbfbfafafaf9fafaf9fafaf9f9f9f9f9f9f8f9f9f8f9f9fcfcfc00000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8f0ebe400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000d6d6d6fefefefcfdfdfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfcfcfbfcfcfbfbfbfbfbfbfb");
        sb.Append("fbfbfafbfbfafafafafafaf9fafaf9fafaf9fafaf9f9f9fcfcfc00000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8f0ebe4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6");
        sb.Append("d6d6fefefefdfdfdfdfdfdfcfdfdfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfcfcfbfcfcfbfbfbfb");
        sb.Append("fbfbfafbfbfafafafafafafafafaf9fafaf9fafafcfdfd00000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6f0ebe4e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0");
        sb.Append("d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8e0d6c8ea");
        sb.Append("eaea000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fe");
        sb.Append("fefefdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfcfdfdfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfcfcfb");
        sb.Append("fbfbfafbfbfafbfbd6d6d6cececebfbfbfb8b8b800000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfc");
        sb.Append("fdfdfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfbfbb2b2b2abababa9a9a9a9a9a9afafafb7b7b700");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fefefefd");
        sb.Append("fdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfcfdfdfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfbfbc6");
        sb.Append("c6c6f5f5f5f4f4f4e3e3e3bbbbbb62626200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000d6d6d6fefefefefefefdfefefdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfcfdfdfcfcfcfc");
        sb.Append("fcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfbfcfcfbfcfccececefafafaebebebc9c9c96c6c6c00000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fffefeece9e9c4");
        sb.Append("bfbff2eff0fdfdfdece9e9c4bfbff2eff0fcfcfcece9e9c4bfbff2eff0fcfcfcfcfcfccdcdcde4");
        sb.Append("e4e4c8c8c866666600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000d6d6d6fffefebdb8b8000000dddadafdfdfdbdb8b8000000dddadafcfdfdbd");
        sb.Append("b8b8000000dddadafcfcfceaeaeac3c3c3c7c7c763636300000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d6d6d6fffefeece9e9c4bfbff3");
        sb.Append("f0f0fdfdfdece9e9c4bfbff3f0f0fdfdfdece9e9c4bfbff3f0f0fcfcfcdcdcdcbfbfbfaeacac00");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("0000000000d6d6d6d6d6d6d6d6d6f6f3f3d6d6d6d6d6d6d6d6d6f6f3f3d6d6d6d6d6d6d6d6d6f6");
        sb.Append("f3f3d6d6d6d6d6d6ccccccc3c1c1c7c7c700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        sb.Append("000005000000020101000000050000002e01060000000a0000002105080066696c652e74787421");
        sb.Append("0014001c000000fb021000070000000000bc02000000000102022253797374656d0000c92c6687");
        sb.Append("00000a0022008a0100000000ffffffff0caeef06040000002d010100030000000000");
        sb.Append("}}}\\par");
        sb.Append("}");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: executing your code, I get `changes until repeat: 1
changes until staying equal:1` - am I missing something?

Comment: @KeithHall thanks for running the code. When I execute it, I get `changes until repeat: xxx` and a never ending loop... the code I run is exactly the code I posted, so it seems like it depends on other conditions :-/

Comment: @KeithHall after playing around with different versions of the .net framework I experience the same behaviour as you. Sorry for waisting your time, I'll have to dig deeper

Comment: no worries, happy to help - hope you find the solution :)

Comment: @KeithHall what .Net Version did you use? The described behaviour is gone as soon as I change from my default (4.5.2) to 4 or earlier. Changig to 4.5 or higher does not change the behaviour

Comment: I'm using 4.5.2 - executing from LinqPad v5.10.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for trying and reproducing. I am using Win7, VS2015 Communtiy. Let's see what Microsoft Support has to say about that

Comment: @Breeze I also observed the same behavior when attaching Images(VS 2017) ..have you found any work around for RTF string comparison ?

Comment: @JharPaat I didn't find any, sorry. In the end, we made kind of a workaround, where the files were stored another way with placeholders linking to them